# How to get the "Copy Video Url" link of any youtube video in java

Tags: javascript, java, browser, youtube-api

Play any youtube video in browser and right click on the video . You will see "Copy Video Url" . How to get this url from any java code or using youtube api .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: java or javascript?

Comment: @Stu Need is java . If not possible javascript will also help .

Comment: Have you tried checking the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the video's URL, and know the time you want it to start, all you need to do is add &t=#m#s to the end of the URL. If you're on a page with a youtube video and you want to get the current time, you need to use Javascript:

```
ytplayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");
ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
```

Appending to the URL:

```
String urlWithTime = url + "&t=" + mins + "m" + secs + "s";
```